# How to remove data from form field after refreshing?

Tags: javascript

I made a form with text fields,i want that data in the form should clear after pressing F5 key.

By reloading this is happening.

Any suggestion......

Comment: How to preserve tell me that, definitely after pressing F5 it will get clear as far as I know. "By reloading this is happening.", i think this is nothing but pressing F5.

Comment: Well, you could do some window.onbeforeunload stuff that clear the form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The F5 is under the control of the browser so you can't do anything about it. But you can place a reset button on your form.

Comment: "i want that data in the form should clear after pressing F5 key." I think this is what default behavior is, then why you are mentioning as it is not under our control?

Comment: @Jayesh The f5 key is set by the browser ad it is the browser that decides whether or not to refresh the entire contents of the page or fetch the page from cache. Some browsers allow you to use the shift (or is it ctrl) to force a page refresh. If the OP was instructing their users of clearing the form it is better to put a reset button on the form as this is what the button was intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`autocomplete="off"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-autocomplete). See also [*How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion* at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion).